# Facing issue to save post data using saveMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, orm

I've Below database Structure.

I have users and a single user have many passports so I created a relation like user hasMany passports and passport belongTo the user In Respected Models.

When I update the user details, & enter 2-3 passport numbers and try to save data in user_passport table using saveMany. Primary key id and user_id saved in the database but passport number is NULL. Here is the saving process:

```
$user = $this->find($id); 
$user->passports()->delete(); 
$new[] = new UserPassport(['passport' => '123456789', 'created_by' => $user->id, 'updated_by' => $user->id]); 
$new[] = new UserPassport(['passport' => '111111111', 'created_by' => $user->id, 'updated_by' => $user->id]); 
$user->passports()->saveMany($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to accomplish what you want. You could simply do something like this:

```
$user->passports()->delete();

$user->passports()->create(['passport' => '123456789', 'created_by' => $user->id, 'updated_by' => $user->id]);
$user->passports()->create(['passport' => '123456789', 'created_by' => $user->id, 'updated_by' => $user->id]);
```

Yeah, that will run separate queries, but the code is very clear and readable.

Comment: Yes I know, save and create already working for me but I wish to save all the records together in place of hitting 5-6 queries to Mysql for insert. That is why saveMany comes in market.

Comment: Check if  'passport' field is specified in UserPassport class $fillable array.

Comment: Yes dear its fillable and try it without fillable to..but the result was same.